# Programming in BIOS

Tags: assembly, bios

I am a C# developer and mostly work with web.

Here is what I want:
I want to create a routine that runs directly on the machine (independent of OS) so that if I reinstall the OS then my routine is still there.

Basically I want to create an anti theft system . that routine will get the gps location of the laptop and will send it to a specific email.

I think it can only be done in BIOS level programming but I am not finding the first step.

Comment: I don't think that's easily possible without **A** dedicated hardware or **B** some serious hacking of BIOS. But otherwise a **plausible project that would make you a fortune**.

Comment: Most BIOS vendors make this hard (intentionally). Check out [coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org/) though as an open source extensible starting point.

Comment: @Flexo: put it in an answer. This is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Flexo, nice link.

Comment: Nice book on this topic can be downloaded... [BIOS Ninjitsu](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3296)

Comment: So I can nick your laptop as long as I flash the bios before connecting it to the internet then?

Comment: you are right tony , but most of the machines will be recoverable by this routine.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Actually, you could do this by writing a hypervisor.

Comment: @SLaks: That's a nice idea, but easy to circumvent by either reinstalling the whole system or simply replacing the disk. Hypervisor is just installable software (I tend to think of it as a super lightweight OS that does one thing and one thing only - serve clients their hardware). Putting stuff in BIOS would prevent this circumvention. It would always run regardless of disk or OS changes.

Comment: Yes, hacking BIOS is possible and had been done already. Search for 'hacking BIOS' in google (and variations). You can find even examples - I found some when was interested in this topic. It was related to some pretty old BIOS (Pentium 4 era), but at least, you get an idea.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: An extremely clever hypervisor could be completely indestructible within the OS (search Google for blue pill virus); it would only be circumventable by powering down, then booting to alternate media.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditional PC BIOS vendors go to lengths to keep their assets secret. This makes BIOS level programming exceedingly hard. It's specific to the vendor of the BIOS, the specific build for the specific hardware it runs on and you'll be patching binaries to inject your code.

Motherboards which have two (or more) EEPROMs for the BIOS make work like this possible for not much cash outlay - it makes sure if you mess things up you still have a way of booting and re-flashing the image you broke.

[Coreboot](http://coreboot.org) is a free software alternative that aims to cut traditional closed BIOS vendors out of the boot process. It's extensible (very little ASM) and open source which makes it a good place to start looking if you want to develop BIOS extensions.

EFI on newer hardware changes the picture quite significantly too. You could present your software as an [EFI extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Extensions) on an internal USB device for example.

Comment: +1... It amuses me to think of EFI extension development. How do you debug such stuff without any serious emulator? Trying out each version is a very time consuming task without it. Which brings me back to nineties when I was bitching about slow C++ compiler/linker... :)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - with EFI at least virtualising it is (sometimes) a sane way to go about it at least.

Comment: Is that possible? To have particular virtual machnes running particular EFI extensions? I mean without running the same extension on host machine?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik [VMware certainly supports EFI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21517126) so it's at least theoretically possible even if people aren't actually doing that yet.